# In html table, change first cell of each data row to <th scope="row">, instead of a <td> element, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, html-table

I'm trying to use jQuery to change the first cell in each row of an HTML table so that, instead of a `<td>` element, it will instead be `<th scope="row">`. The full table, which is produced using d3, is available in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQesVq9gu9cCu0o2oxMK?p=preview). 
Here's an excerpt:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Total</td>
   <td>36,000</td>
   <td>6,118</td>
   <td>5,034</td>
   <td>5,496</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Percent_patients</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>16.8</td>
   <td>13.8</td>
   <td>15.1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What I'm trying to do is make it like this:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Total</th>
   <td>36,000</td>
   <td>6,118</td>
   <td>5,034</td>
   <td>5,496</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Percent_patients</th>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>16.8</td>
   <td>13.8</td>
   <td>15.1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I've tried to follow similar examples here on SO, but I'm having trouble with even the first steps, i.e. selecting the first cell of each row (and changing anything about it). For example, I've tried adding `$("#switchable-table tr td:first-child").addClass("black");`, but this doesn't seem to register.

Is anyone able to demonstrate a solution, based on [my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQesVq9gu9cCu0o2oxMK?p=preview)?

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) whenever possible for runnable **on-site** examples, rather than **off-site** resources like Plunker. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: As far as **providing a d3 based code snippet (ones which include fetching of local files)**, it's easier to use external resources rather than SO's Stack-snippet. I don't see a way to upload local files in the Stack Snippet and use it in `d3` code. If there's one, please let me know as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Shashank - I said "whenever possible" for a reason. :-) Certainly the OP's code is easily included in a snippet; see my answer.

Comment: I could not find the `switchable-table` id in your code, even by the inspector after executing the script, you just used a class instead. Did you test that?

Comment: @LaissezPasser - [JoeKincognito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935488/157247) is a perfect example of why you should prefer **on-site** to **off-site**. Questions must be self-contained and include all the necessary information. By leaving off the `table` tags in the markup, you left out important information (that you'd used `class="switchable-table"` rather than `id="switchable-table"`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Oh re-read your comment. Yep, whenever possible. I've posted a `d3` way of doing it. Anyway, hope something works out.

Comment: @Shashank It is easy to link to a version of d3 hosted at d3js.org and create (or copy/paste) some appropriate sample data for a lot of d3 questions.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Agreed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `d3` way of doing it. You don't need to use **jQuery**.

1. Took off the `d.index` from the `td`s that you append.
2. Append the `d.index` using another selection.

**Relevant code:**

```
trs.selectAll('th')
    .data(function (d) { return [d.index]; })
    .enter()
    .append('th')
    .attr('scope', 'row')
    .text(function (d) { return d; });
```

And here's the updated Plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JKaSXMiegsPdmv3fBVOK?p=preview

Also, in the step where you bind `data` to the `td`s, you can replace it with `headers` array which already has all the necessary headers. Here:

```
trs.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(d){ return headers.map(function(key) { return d[key];}); })
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to use jQuery to change the first cell in each row of an HTML table so that, instead of a `<td> element` it will be a `<th scope="row">`" - while you can change this after the fact, why would you want to do it this way? Instead of changing the element after the fact you could append a th element to start with.

Here you append your td elements for each row:

```
    trs.selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d){ return [d.index, d['Total'],   d['PRIMARY Alcohol only'],  d['Alcohol with secondary drug'],   d['Heroin'],    d['Other opiates'], d['Cocaine (smoked)'],  d['Cocaine (other route)'], d['Marijuana'], d['Amphetamines'],  d['Other stimulants'],  d['Tranquilizers'], d['Sedatives'], d['Hallucinogens'], d['PCP'],   d['Inhalants'], d['Other/Unknown']]; })
      .enter()
      .append('td')
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      });
```

Instead append the th and then go through the enter cycle to enter the rest of the tds:

```
    trs.append("th")
      .text(function(d) { return d.index; })
      .attr("scope","row")

    trs.selectAll('td')
      .data(function(d){ return [d['Total'],    d['PRIMARY Alcohol only'],  d['Alcohol with secondary drug'],   d['Heroin'],    d['Other opiates'], d['Cocaine (smoked)'],  d['Cocaine (other route)'], d['Marijuana'], d['Amphetamines'],  d['Other stimulants'],  d['Tranquilizers'], d['Sedatives'], d['Hallucinogens'], d['PCP'],   d['Inhalants'], d['Other/Unknown']]; })
      .enter()
      .append('td')
      .text(function(d){
        return d;
      });
```

Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5n1nGycn1vIMHHM92e8Z?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

To select the first cell in each row, you'd use the [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), since you know the first child will be the cell. You've said that doesn't work, but it does (if I assume you have `id="switchable-table"` on the table). :-) Perhaps you were running your `$(...)` function too early: Put your `script` tags at the very end of the document, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag.

To replace one element with another, you'd use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).

So:

```
$("#switchable-table tr td:first-child").replaceWith('<th scope="row"></th>');
```

It's smart enough to replace each element individually.

```js
$("#switchable-table tr td:first-child").replaceWith('<th scope="row"></th>');
```

```html
<table id="switchable-table">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Total</td>
   <td>36,000</td>
   <td>6,118</td>
   <td>5,034</td>
   <td>5,496</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Percent_patients</td>
   <td>100</td>
   <td>16.8</td>
   <td>13.8</td>
   <td>15.1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I've tried adding $("#switchable-table tr td:first-child").addClass("black");

switchable-table isn't an ID it's a class so...

```
$(".switchable-table tr td:first-child").addClass("black");
```